# Publishing config and migrations from included package in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, package

I'm using Laravel to build a package which will include some Admin functionality and will include some other packages.

I have included a package which has migrations and a config file, But how do I copy those to the correct folder in Laravel. The package has it's own ServiceProvider but How do I call that from my package?

I'm using the following to register the package in my package.

```
class CldServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
       $this->app->register(MediaLibraryServiceProvider::class);
    }
}
```

I've tried

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

But it says there's nothing to publish. Because it's only looking at the packages for this Laravel installation, and not the nested packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case I found I needed to include MY package in the application I was working on. This step was not included in the original tutorial I followed.

So in `composer.json` in the main app:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "packages/namespace/name",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    // ...
    "namespace/name": "dev-master"
},
```

And then we run this command from main folder:

`composer update`

After that running `php artisan vendor:publish` will include the option to publish the sub packages.

NB: The source for this info is: https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-a-laravel-5-package-in-10-easy-steps/

Answer (score 4):

Create `database/migrations` folder in your package root folder. Then add publish details in boot method in your service provider.

```php
final class MyPackageServiceProvider extends BaseServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/../database/migrations/' => database_path('migrations/my-package'),
        ], 'my-package-migrations');
    }
}
```

Second part could be like `database_path('migrations')` or `database_path('migrations/my-package')`. I advise using with subfolder because if there are many packages `migrations` folder grows too much.

The part of `'my-package-migrations'` is our tag. And run publish command with tag.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=my-package-migrations
```

If you are using the subfolder `php artisan migrate` command won't work because we need to specify to exact migration folder like this,

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/my-package
```

Yes, this looks a little bit dirty but organizes cables. And don't forget the using `composer dump-autoload`. If the service provider is registered this solution works. Also, you can use this method for config but config folder does not support subfolders.

Answer (score 3):

Try to publish the config separately and use the force switch

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=config --force
```

Answer (score 2):

As @scrubmx mentioned, you need to include the code that defines what can be published, though this code shouldn't really be in your own service provider, but rather the other package you're including. If it doesn't seem to have this code, it's best to list it as an issue on that package's repository or create a pull request to add it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the other package has its own service provider but I don't know how to call it.. Do you know how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have publish the config files yourself

```
$this->publishes([
    'other-package/absolute/path/some-config.php' => config_path('my-package.php'),
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Seems weird that you would have to do this for all packages you include? But it could be!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I included the /packages/ folder in my current project where I was working on.
The problem is that when including the package in my composer.json

> It is now reachable from 2 places inside my project, in the vendor folder and in my packages folder. This was causing issue's

I moved my packages outside my current project, this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Publish vendor migration :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=migration
```

Publish vendor config :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=config
```

Answer (score 0):

you have running this code, this code must be written in boot method.

```
// run dependency publishable
$this->publishes(self::pathsToPublish(MediaLibraryServiceProvider::class), 'sample-group');
```

You can go to the example written in the boot function [in this package](https://github.com/jobmetric/translation/blob/master/src/Providers/TranslationServiceProvider.php)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the times when I still wrote PHP! :)

Comment: You disappointed me!!  :)